# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php-qt-ng.so' - php-qt-ng.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI7QObject in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, c++, apache, qt

I installed PHP-CPP. After that I compiled and installed php-qt-ng. When I tried to debug given example test.php I got this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php-qt-ng.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php-qt-ng.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI7QObject in Unknown on line 0

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Try compiling with `-no-rtti`.

Comment: Undefined symbol now became _ZNK7QObject10metaObjectEv